# UITableviewcell not dequeing and being copied by cell at same index in different section

Tags: swift

I have a uitableview that loads strings from an array into the section and then adds a blank cell onto the end of each of the sections, the only problem is it's not working correctly. I think its because of one of the cells not resetting nor responding to any code that attempts to change it. The picture below shows the problem, notice how theres a blank cell at the end of the instructions section, but theres no blank cell at the end of the ingredients section. Instead the cell copied from row 4 from the instructions section is now put into the ingredients section at the same row where a blank cell should be.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJUBG.jpg)

The code for the cellForRowAt is below along with the tableviewcellclass and revelant code.

CellForRowAt and relevant code

```
var numberOfIngredients : Int = temporaryRecipeItem.ingredients.count + 1
var numberOfInstructions : Int = temporaryRecipeItem.instructions.count + 1

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = creationTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeInstructionsCell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeInstructionsCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    cell.tableViewMaster = self.creationTableView
    cell.delegate = self

    print(indexPath.section,indexPath.row)
    cell.cellTextView.text = ""
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row < numberOfIngredients - 1 {
        cell.cellTextView.text = temporaryRecipeItem.ingredients[indexPath.row]

    } else if indexPath.row < numberOfInstructions - 1 {
        cell.cellTextView.text = temporaryRecipeItem.instructions[indexPath.row]
        //print(cell.cellTextView.text!)
    }
    print(cell.cellTextView.text!)
    return cell
}
```

TableViewCellClass

```
class RecipeInstructionsCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var cellTextView: UITextView!
var indexPath : IndexPath?
var tableViewMaster : UITableView?
var delegate : RecipeInstructionsCellProtocol?
var hasAddedRow : Bool = false

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.cellTextView.delegate = self
    self.cellTextView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    self.cellTextView.autocorrectionType = .yes
    self.cellTextView.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
    //self.cellTextView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    self.cellTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
    self.cellTextView.textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
    self.cellTextView.returnKeyType = .next
    self.cellTextView.text = ""
}


func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let size = textView.bounds.size
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    if size.height != newSize.height {
        self.tableViewMaster?.beginUpdates()
        self.tableViewMaster?.endUpdates()

        //let thisIndexPath = IndexPath(row: textView.tag, section: 0)
    }
    delegate?.editText(at: (self.indexPath!))
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    delegate?.saveText(at: self.indexPath!, text: self.cellTextView.text)
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        if tableViewMaster!.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.indexPath!.row + 1, section: self.indexPath!.section)) != nil {
            self.cellTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            let cell = tableViewMaster?.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.indexPath!.row + 1, section: self.indexPath!.section)) as! RecipeInstructionsCell
            cell.cellTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change

```
} else if indexPath.row < numberOfInstructions - 1
```

to

```
} else if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row < numberOfInstructions - 1
```

Comment: I'm actually mad at myself for not finding this xD, but thank you for pointing it out Chris! :)